Installing application on Windows container
I'm trying to install my application using a Windows container.
The installation copies the files that are needed and runs a Windows service as a local system when the installer finishes copying the files.
The problem that I have is that the service can't start because I don't have sufficient privileges to run it.
I'm using the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 image.
I have to install my application's MSI because it's part of my integration tests that are written in C#.
I tried to run as ContainerAdministrator, create a new user in the Administrator group, run as an NT Authority\System user, and login as an administrator. I searched everywhere for the problem, but I couldn't find any solution.
Most of the people created the service within the Dockerfile, but this is not what I need. I have to use the installer as is, and I can't change it.

Have you tried to do this process without changing the user context? By default, you will be running with the ContainerAdministrator account and could check if it's an installation issue or something else.

I tried to do this process without changing the user and on my local computer the installation is working and also the service.

Great, have you tried on the container itself without changing the user profile?

Eventually, I found the problem and fixed it.
I tried to isolate the problem and I found out that the Windows Container couldn't start my Windows service that I created using exe from my.NET 6 application. Every time that I tried to start the service, I had a timeout.
If someone tries to create a Windows service using the.NET 6 application, make sure that the NuGets Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting and Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices are updated to the latest version
I used version 6.0.0 (that what caused the problem) and every time I tried to run my Windows service on Windows Container, I had a timeout and the service couldn't start.
I hope this will help someone who is having the same issue.
